# How to identify binary and text files using Python?

Tags: python, text, binary, file-type

I need identify which **file** is **binary** and which is a **text** in a directory.

I tried use *mimetypes* but it isnt a good idea in my case because it cant identify all files mimes, and I have strangers ones here... I just need know, binary or text. Simple ? But I couldn´t find a solution...

Thanks

Comment: What is a text file for you? Does UTF-16-BE encoded Unicode count, for example?

Comment: You need to define precisely what is meant by 'binary' and 'text' before anyone can help you.

Comment: Text file is any file that is readable by humans. Say, any file that you can read by a "cat" (linux) or "type" (windows) command.

Comment: This similar question has a few good answers, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898669/how-can-i-detect-if-a-file-is-binary-non-text-in-python  file(1) is pretty reliable, so you could go with the pure-python solution that is based on file(1) behaviour; or you could trust the mimetypes module.

Comment: Use this library:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/binaryornot/

It is very simple and based on code found in this stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks everybody, I found a solution that suited my problem. I found this code at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/173220/ and I changed just a little piece to suit me.

It works fine.

```
from __future__ import division
import string 

def istext(filename):
    s=open(filename).read(512)
    text_characters = "".join(map(chr, range(32, 127)) + list("\n\r\t\b"))
    _null_trans = string.maketrans("", "")
    if not s:
        # Empty files are considered text
        return True
    if "\0" in s:
        # Files with null bytes are likely binary
        return False
    # Get the non-text characters (maps a character to itself then
    # use the 'remove' option to get rid of the text characters.)
    t = s.translate(_null_trans, text_characters)
    # If more than 30% non-text characters, then
    # this is considered a binary file
    if float(len(t))/float(len(s)) > 0.30:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: A little correction for your code :
`if float(len(t))/float(len(s)) > 0.30:
    return 0`
Otherwise, python will use the integer division, and the comparison will only be true when len(t) == len(s)

Comment: Thomas, please apply that "float" correction to the answer!  Activestate should fix their recipe, too!  ;)  but I can't be bothered signing up to bump the comments there.

Comment: also there is a trailing * on the last line, should not be there

Comment: @cedriv-julien, @sam-watkins, I think it's fine without the use of `float`, because of the `from __future__ import division` line, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, he changed that recently.  I would prefer not to change the meaning of division throughout my program.  And the original code at activestate lacks that line.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'map' and 'list'

Comment: This code is not valid for python 3

Answer (score 8):

It's inherently *not* simple. There's no way of knowing for sure, although you can take a reasonably good guess in most cases.

Things you might like to do:

- Look for known magic numbers in binary signatures
- Look for the Unicode byte-order-mark at the start of the file
- If the file is regularly 00 xx 00 xx 00 xx (for arbitrary xx) or vice versa, that's quite possibly UTF-16
- Otherwise, look for 0s in the file; a file with a 0 in is *unlikely* to be a single-byte-encoding text file.

But it's all heuristic - it's quite possible to have a file which is a valid text file *and* a valid image file, for example. It would probably be nonsense as a text file, but legitimate in some encoding or other...

Answer (score 7):

It might be possible to use [libmagic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libmagic) to guess the MIME type of the file using [python-magic](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic/). If you get back something in the ["text/*"](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/) namespace, it is likely a text file, while anything else is likely a [binary file](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html).

Answer (score 5):

If your script is running on *nix, you could use something like this:

```
import subprocess
import re

def is_text(fn):
    msg = subprocess.Popen(["file", fn], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    return re.search('text', msg) != None
```

Comment: No need for `re` if just finding substring.

Comment: Doesn't work if `text` is part of a binary's file filepath.

Comment: I suggest  Popen(["file", "--mime", fn]. ...). Otherwise the word "text" might not appear. On my Linux, the answer for something that looks like a Fortran program is "FORTAN program". If you add the mime switch you get "text/x-fortran; charset=us-ascii".

Comment: If you're using Python 3 the `msg` will be bytes rather than a string, so you'd have to use `return re.search("text", msg.decode()) != None` or `return "text" in msg.decode()` instead.