# How to identify binary and text files using Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, pharo, file-type, visualworks

I want to verify that a given file in a path is of type text file, i.e. not binary, i.e. readable by a human. I guess reading first characters and check each character with :

- isAlphaNumeric
- isSpecial
- isSeparator
- isOctetCharacter ???

but joining all those testing methods with and: [ ... and: [ ... and: [ ] ] ] seems not to be very smalltalkish. Any suggestion for a more elegant way?

(There is a Python version here [How to identify binary and text files using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446549/how-to-identify-binary-and-text-files-using-python) which could be useful but syntax and implementation looks like C.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only heuristics; you can never be really certain...

For ascii, the following may do:

```
|isPlausibleAscii numChecked|

isPlausibleAscii := 
    [:char |
        ((char codePoint between:32 and:127)
        or:[ char isSeparator ])
    ].

numChecked := text size min: 1024.
isPossiblyText := text from:1 to:numChecked conform: isPlausibleAscii.
```

For unicode (UTF8 ?) things become more difficult; you could then try to convert. If there is a conversion error, assume binary.

PS: if you don't have from:to:conform:, replace by (copyFrom:to:) conform:

PPS: if you don't have conform: , try allSatisfy:

Answer (score 0):

All text contains more space than you'd expect to see in a binary file, and some encodings (UTF16/32) will contain lots of 0's for common languages.
A smalltalky solution would be to hide the gory details in method on Standard/MultiByte-FileStream, #isProbablyText would probably be a good choice.

It would essentially do the following:
- store current state if you intend to use it later, reset to start (Set Latin1 converter if you use a MultiByteStream)

- Iterate over N  next characters (where N is an appropriate number)
- Encounter a non-printable ascii char? It's probably binary, so return false.  (not a special selector, use a map, implement a new method on Character or something)
- Increase 2 counters if appropriate, one for space characters, and another for zero characters.
- If loop finishes, return whether either of the counters have been read a statistically significant amount

TLDR; Use a method to hide the gory details, otherwise it's pretty much the same.