# How can I force Python's file.write() to use the same newline format in Windows as in Linux ("\r\n" vs. "\n")?

Tags: python, newline

I have the simple code:

```
f = open('out.txt','w')
f.write('line1\n')
f.write('line2')
f.close()
```

Code runs on windows and gives file size `12 bytes`, and linux gives `11 bytes`
The reason is new line

In linux it's `\n` and for win it is `\r\n`

But in my code I specify new line as `\n`. The question is how can I make python keep new line as `\n` always, and not check the operating system.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You need to open the file in *binary mode* i.e. `wb` instead of `w`. If you don't, the end of line characters are auto-converted to OS specific ones.

Here is an excerpt from Python reference about [`open()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open).

> The default is to use text mode, which may convert '\n' characters to a platform-specific representation on writing and back on reading.

Comment: In Python 3, since strings are not encoded, you will need to write them with something like `outfile.write(bytes(line, "UTF-8"))` to avoid a `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`.

Comment: You do not _need_ to open the file in binary mode, it is one way to solve it but not the only one

Answer (score 28):

Du kannst den Textmodus verwenden und trotzdem `'\n'` als  Zeilenumbruch verwenden. Dafür musst du den Parameter `newline` setzen wenn du die Datei öffnest.

```
f = open("./foo",'w',newline='\n')

f.write("Zeile 1\n")
print("Noch eine Zeile", file=f)
```

Getestet Mit Python 3.4.2. Funktioniert nicht in Python 2.7.

Comment: I've defined the `newline` as suggested, but the `f.write()` commands don't automatically insert this between writes. How to do that?

Comment: ok my bad. If it helps, I found that once `newline='\r\n'` or anything is specified in the open() command, we don't need to worry about putting the 'right' newline in the `write()` commands. We just need to say `\n` and that will get replaced with the custom newline string we have configured.

Answer (score 11):

This is an old answer, but the `io.open` function lets you to specify the line endings:

```
import io
with io.open('tmpfile', 'w', newline='\r\n') as f:
    f.write(u'foo\nbar\nbaz\n')
```

From : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2642121/6271889

Comment: As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.open) states, the function `io.open` is just an alias for the built-in function [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). There is no difference between them.