# write the screen output into the file

Tags: python

I got a question about redirect the screen output into a single file. Here is my code to print the screen output:

```
for O,x,y,z,M,n in coordinate:
    print(O,x,y,z,M,n)
```

And the screen output looks like:

```
O 0 0 0 ! 1
O 1 0 0 ! 2 
O 2 0 0 ! 3
```

So how can I redirect all the data into a single file and in the same format, just like the screen output. Because it will be mush faster to get all the data rather than waiting for the screen output to finish.
I tried`for point in coordinate:
        file.write(' '.join(str(s) for s in point))` but output file became:

```
O 0 0 0 ! 0O 1 0 0 ! 1O 2 0 0 ! 2O 3 0 0 ! 3O 4 0 0 ! 4O 5 0 0 ! 5O 6 0 0 ! 6O
```

Comment: You should narrow down your question. Rather than paste in all of your code, just paste in what `coordinate` might look like at the end of all those loops.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/616686/5987

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is not to do it in Python, but let the OS do it for you. This works both in Linux and the Windows command prompt.

```
python myprog.py >output.txt
```

Comment: This is in my opinion the best way to handle this, unless of course the actual goal of your program is to write the output to files. Then it's probably better to handle it in code, otherwise properly running the code requires knowing that you have to run it like this.

Comment: @kniteli My goal is to redirect all the screen output into a single file. I am a novice in python and I have been struggled in this problem all day.

Answer (score 1):

The function call `file.write(*point)` essentially takes each element inside the `point` list, and modifies the function call to look like this: `file.write(p1, p2, p3, p4, ...)`.

However, `file.write` takes in only a single argument -- a string. That means you need to transform the `point` list into a string.

It will probably end up looking like this:

```
with open('substrate', 'w') as file:
    for point in coordinate:
        file.write(' '.join([str(p) for p in point])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
with open('substrate', 'wb') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(' '.join(str(p) for p in point)) for point in coordinate)
```

If you are wondering why `wb`? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184107/python-file-write-new-line)

If you want to go with `Mark Ransom`'s answer, I believe this is how you do it in code:

```
from sys import stdout
stdout.write('\n'.join(' '.join(str(p) for p in point)) for point in coordinate)
```

Comment: I tried your code. But I my output file only contains:s s ss s, etc.

Comment: @JianliCheng

OK, it seems you are using python 3. See update code

Comment: The output file is still not I am looking for. In the output file, n jump to the 10, then 20,30,40,etc., not 1,2,3,4,5...Also, how can I make each line in the output file that is only occupied by one point, like: O 0 0 0 ! 1/n O 1 0 0! 2/n

Comment: @JianliCheng

Update your original post with the output you get in your file when you use this code

Comment: @JianliCheng I see where your problem is, I will update my post in a minute

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for, so I'm going two routes.

```
for coordset in coordinate:
    for point in coordset:
        file.write(point)
```

Or, if you want formatting, you can use a formatting string.

```
for coordset in coordinate:
    file.write('%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s' % set)
```

You can clarify your post if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Note that `set` is a keyword in python. So you might have to consider changing that name to something else more suited for this