# Avoid writing carriage return '\r' when writing line feed with Python

Tags: python, carriage-return, linefeed

If taken into consideration that `carriage return = \r` and `line feed = \n`

```
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> '{:02x}'.format(ord('\n'))
'0a'
>>> '{:02x}'.format(ord('\r'))
'0d'
```

how to avoid writing carriage return when using `open('filename','w').write('text\n')` ?

In interactive mode you can do this:

```
>>> open('filename','w').write('text\n')
5
>>> for c in open('filename','r').read():
...     print('{:02x}'.format(ord(c)))
...
74
65
78
74
0a
```

This would indicate that only line feed has been written, thus it should be 5 bytes long.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 djuric 197121        6 Jul 15 21:00 filename
                                  ^
```

It is actually 6 bytes long. Now this can be a "Windows thing", but when you open the file in Notepad++ for example, and you turn **View > Show Symbols > Show All Characters** you can see the carriage return there.

After pressing CTRL+H and replacing \r with nothing using Extended Search Mode, only line feed is left. After saving the file, only line feed is in the file and the file is 5 bytes long.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 djuric 197121    5 Jul 15 20:58 filename1
                              ^
```

So why is Notepad++ able to save line feeds without carriage return, but python can't?

Comment: I still want to write only \n, I don't care what operating system does. If I want to specify specific characters to be written, then that's what I should be able to do.

Comment: I updated the question, maybe you will find it not worth downvoting... and actually think about the answer

Comment: You can't avoid writing a carriage return when using `open('name', 'w')` because mode `w - write,text` is a mode which changes LF into CRLF implicitly. You need to open the file in binary mode with `'wb'`.

Comment: `open('filename','wb').write(bytes('text\n','UTF-8'))` works. Thanks @TessellatingHeckler

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184107/how-can-i-force-pythons-file-write-to-use-the-same-newline-format-in-windows/37706497

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do this by passing `''` to the `newline` parameter when opening the text file.

```
f = open('test.txt', 'w', newline='')
f.write('Only LF\n')
f.write('CR + LF\r\n')
f.write('Only CR\r')
f.write('Nothing')
f.close()
```

As described in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open):

> newline controls how universal newlines mode works (it only applies to
>   text mode). It can be None, '', '\n', '\r', and '\r\n'. It works as
>   follows:
>
> - When reading input from the stream, if newline is None, universal newlines mode is enabled. Lines in the input can end in '\n', '\r', or
>     '\r\n', and these are translated into '\n' before being returned to
>     the caller. **If it is '', universal newlines mode is enabled, but line
>     endings are returned to the caller untranslated.** If it has any of the
>     other legal values, input lines are only terminated by the given
>     string, and the line ending is returned to the caller untranslated.
> - When writing output to the stream, if newline is None, any '\n' characters written are translated to the system default line
>     separator, os.linesep. If newline is '' or '\n', no translation takes
>     place. If newline is any of the other legal values, any '\n'
>     characters written are translated to the given string.

The default value for `newline` is `None`, by specifiying `''`, you're forcing Python to write the newline (`\n` or `\r`) without translating it.

Comment: this is what I was looking for, although I did it using binary mode

Comment: this helped me a lot!