# writing chr(13) to file gives chr(10) when read

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, carriage-return, linefeed

I have a simple piece of code that breaks my mind:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    writen_text = chr(13)
    file = open('bug', 'w')
    file.write(writen_text)
    file.close()
    file = open('bug')
    read_text = ''.join(file.readlines())
    print([ord(c) for c in writen_text])
    print([ord(c) for c in read_text])
    assert writen_text == read_text
```

The output is

```
[13]
[10]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bug.py", line 10, in <module>
    assert writen_text == read_text
AssertionError
```

What is this??? I just want to write a text to a file and read exactly this text without any changes

Python3.6.6, Ubuntu18.04, if it matters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you notice, starting with `chr(10)` remains the same and passes your assertion test.

So the real question is why is the `chr(13)` being changed into a `chr(10)`?  In order to answer that, we have to look at what each of these characters actually represent.  The `chr(13)` is a carriage return character while the `chr(10)` is a line feed character.

You mentioned that you are using a Linux box.  Linux, utilizing the Unix model, uses the Line Feed character and does not use the Carriage Return character in it's files.  Therefore, when writing the `CR` character to the file, the system is translating it to the `LF` character used by the system.  Then, you are reading the file (with the translated character) and thus failing your assertion.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3098328/9110408) a good post on the differences in types of returns.

Comment: Specifically, Python's [file object](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open) does the conversion. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404827/avoid-writing-carriage-return-when-writing-line-feed-with-python.