# Python binascii.unhexlify is converting linefeed characters. Can I prevent this?

Tags: python, binascii

I have an string of pairs of characters representing hex numbers, (e.g. 0f means decimal 15).
I need this in binary format, so I called 
`binArray = binascii.unhexlify(finalString)`

I have "bash on Ubuntu on Windows" installed, and  when I perform this from there it works fine.

However, I need to invoke the script from a .bat file in the windows environment.
When I call the exact same python program from the .bat file, if unhexlify sees '0a' in the hex string it converts it to 0d 0a (in the binary output).
This is not a text file and the line-end conversion is corrupting my data!

Is there a way to convince unhexlify to stop doing this when I call it from the windows environment?

It would seem like a waste to have to roll-my-own conversion.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19)

Comment: The above version is from when I run Python from the Ubunu shell

Comment: I think you need to add more details as to what exactly you are doing.

Comment: When I run Python from a windows cmd shell I get a different python:

Comment: Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: That is all important to note, and you should add that to the question itself, but I mean you should elaborate what more details about your actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why the 0x0A characters were getting converted to 0D0A (I.E. LF to CRLF)

It's not the fault of binascii.
I used

`outfile = open(scriptDir + "Output/NVRAM/NVDATAout", 'w')`
to open the file, which implies text mode, and therefore writes get linefeed conversion appropriate for the local system.

When I opened the output file in binary mode, this conversion stopped happening.

`outfile = open(scriptDir + "Output/NVRAM/NVDATAout", 'wb')`

I found this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9184137/7275012