# .sh file created on windows cannot run on linux

Tags: python, linux, shell

I use python on windows to generate .sh file, simply using `file.open(),file.write()`
. But when I run this .sh on linux, it reports the following error.

**/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory**

The content of my generated .sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
export ICS_START=/rdrive/ics/itools/unx/bin/
source $ICS_START/icssetup.sh
......
```

I found vim recognized it as dos file. I guess if there is something wrong with the newline symbol.

In my python code, I use `file.write('xxxx\n')`. To my knowledge, `'\n'` is the newline on linux/unix and `'\r\n'` is on windows. I don't why there is still `^M` when recognized by linux since I only write `'\n'`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `dos2unix filename.sh` to fix the newlines.

Comment: Python translates `\n` to `\r\n` on WIndows unless you open the file in binary mode.

Comment: @Barmar dos2unix is the method I am using now. I wonder if there is a method to solve it fundamentally.

Comment: In the old days when we used `FTP`, it would automatically convert newlines while transfering. Unfortunately, more modern tools like `scp` don't do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using python to write text files with DOS line endings on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2642036/608639), [How can I force Python's file.write() to use the same newline format in Windows as in Linux (“\r\n” vs. “\n”)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9184107/608639), [How to write Unix end of line characters in Windows using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2536545/608639), [How to convert DOS/Windows newline (CRLF) to Unix newline (LF) in a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2613800/608639), etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash script: bad interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841593/bash-script-bad-interpreter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the file in binary mode, otherwise it translates newlines to the local operating system's format. If you run the script on Windows, that means it converts `\n` to `\r\n` when writing the file.

```
with open("filename.sh", "wb") as file:
```

The `b` in the mode argument tells it to use binary mode.

Comment: Yes. I tried `'wb'` mode using file.write(bytearray(string, 'utf-8')). It works.