# identifying the format of files

Tags: python, file, identification, imghdr

In linux, we have a utility called “file”, which helps us to determine the identification of a file. Is there any python module that can do the same job?

I don't prefer to use `subprocess.Popen(['file', 'blah.blah'])`,
because it is platform dependent. For instance, windows do not have “file” (although it can be downloaded).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898669/how-can-i-detect-if-a-file-is-binary-non-text-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignacio mentioned the Magic library, but you could also do it with the standard library *if* you're confident that the filename is enough to know the file type from (by extension):

```
>>> import mimetypes
>>> mimetypes.guess_type('__init__.py')
('text/x-python', None)
```

See the  [Mimetypes module](http://docs.python.org/library/mimetypes.html) in the standard library. This however isn't a replacement for actually inspecting the content of the file and figuring out its type.

Comment: No, **please** don't see that. "The `mimetypes` module converts between a filename or URL and the MIME type associated with the **filename extension**."

Comment: Oh, that's a good point. If you want it from the content of the file, guess_type isn't what you want. You're right, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 7):

[`magic`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic/)

Don't forget [the DLL](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm).

Answer (score 0):

There are standard modules `imghdr` and `sndhdr` for graphic and sound files, respectively.