# Saving response from Requests to file

Tags: python, file-io, python-requests

I'm using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/) to upload a PDF to an API. It is stored as "response" below. I'm trying to write that out to Excel.

```
import requests

files = {'f': ('1.pdf', open('1.pdf', 'rb'))}
response = requests.post("https://pdftables.com/api?&format=xlsx-single",files=files)
response.raise_for_status() # ensure we notice bad responses
file = open("out.xls", "w")
file.write(response)
file.close()
```

I'm getting the error:

```
file.write(response)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Comment: [`file.write(response.content)`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content).

Comment: `with open(filename, mode='wb') as localfile:
    localfile.write(response.content)`
is more clean and elegant than open and close, IMHO.

Comment: Skip the top two answers and head straight to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65637213/6243352). It'd be nice if OP could move the checkmark to that answer--the existing top answer is pretty much useless and the most-upvoted one is of limited usefulness.

Answer (score -20, accepted):

As [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126596/saving-response-from-requests-to-file#comment50265734_31126596) already pointed out:

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')

In [3]: type(r)
Out[3]: requests.models.Response

In [4]: type(r.content)
Out[4]: str
```

You may also want to check `r.text`.

Also: https://2.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/

Comment: I don't think you answered OP's question. How to save that in a file.  All you did was describe `r`

Answer (score 106):

I believe all the existing answers contain the relevant information, but I would like to summarize.

The response object that is returned by `requests` get and post operations contains two useful attributes:

### Response attributes

- `response.text` - Contains `str` with the response text.
- `response.content` - Contains `bytes` with the **raw** response content.

You should choose one or other of these attributes depending on the type of response you expect.

- For text-based responses (html, json, yaml, etc) you would use `response.text`
- For binary-based responses (jpg, png, zip, xls, etc) you would use `response.content`.

### Writing response to file

When writing responses to file you need to use the [open function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) with the appropriate file write mode.

- For text responses you need to use `"w"` - plain write mode.
- For binary responses you need to use `"wb"` - binary write mode.

### Examples

#### Text request and save

```py
# Request the HTML for this web page:
response = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126596/saving-response-from-requests-to-file")
with open("response.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(response.text)
```

#### Binary request and save

```py
# Request the profile picture of the OP:
response = requests.get("https://i.stack.imgur.com/iysmF.jpg?s=32&g=1")
with open("response.jpg", "wb") as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

### Answering the original question

The original code should work by using `wb` and `response.content`:

```py
import requests

files = {'f': ('1.pdf', open('1.pdf', 'rb'))}
response = requests.post("https://pdftables.com/api?&format=xlsx-single",files=files)
response.raise_for_status() # ensure we notice bad responses
file = open("out.xls", "wb")
file.write(response.content)
file.close()
```

But I would go further and use the `with` [context manager for `open`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html).

```py
import requests

with open('1.pdf', 'rb') as file:
    files = {'f': ('1.pdf', file)}
    response = requests.post("https://pdftables.com/api?&format=xlsx-single",files=files)

response.raise_for_status() # ensure we notice bad responses

with open("out.xls", "wb") as file:
    file.write(response.content)
```

Comment: How to find out which type of file you're getting? For example I'm downloading a file from a link user has given me and I have to find out which type of writing I need to do.

Comment: That's a good question. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/898723/6252525 This suggests using mimetypes.guess_type(), and then use a lookup to determine whether the mime type is binary or not.

Answer (score 51):

You can use the `response.text` to write to a file:

```py
    import requests
    
    files = {'f': ('1.pdf', open('1.pdf', 'rb'))}
    response = requests.post("https://pdftables.com/api?&format=xlsx-single",files=files)
    response.raise_for_status() # ensure we notice bad responses
    with open("resp_text.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(response.text)
```

Comment: or use `with open(...): ...`