# Download folder in python

Tags: python, download

I try download this zip. I used selenium and requests, but neither of them works and I don't know why. 
Thank you for your advice.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

url = 'http://vdp.cuzk.cz/vymenny_format/csv/20200131_OB_ADR_csv.zip'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('drivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

requests.get(url)
```

Comment: Could you give us the stacktrace ?

Comment: `requests.get`, at least, doesn't write anything to the file system. It returns a `Response` object from which you can *read* the contents of the file; it's your responsibility to write that data to a file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving response from Requests to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126596/saving-response-from-requests-to-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requests.get()` downloads the entity into memory. This needs to be explicitly written to a file using open.

Example:

```
import requests

url = 'http://vdp.cuzk.cz/vymenny_format/csv/20200131_OB_ADR_csv.zip'
filename = 'c:/users/user/downloads/csv.zip'

filebody = requests.get(url)
open(filename, 'wb').write(filebody.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need `requests` to download a file (in this case at least). As I don't know the errors you are getting, I would suggest double-checking the path to your chromedriver.exe and you should escape backslashes.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('drivers\\chromedriver.exe')
```

I tried your code (while entering the location of chromedriver on my computer) and it worked - I was able to download the file.