# Download files from a site with requests by clicking the button

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to download download a zip file from this site:

https://resultados.tse.jus.br/oficial/app/index.html#/eleicao/dados-de-urna;e=e545;uf=mg;ufbu=mg;mubu=40037;zn=0001;se=0101/log-da-urna

After clicking the button "download *.zip file" the download is performed.

I'm trying to do this with the resquest because then I want to automate it and just change "zn" and "se" in the ulr

The problem is that I am not able to download the zip file with resquests

This is the code i'm trying, can anyone help me?

```
import py7zr
import json
import requests

r = requests.get('https://resultados.tse.jus.br/oficial/ele2022/arquivo-urna/407/dados/mg/40037/0001/0101/494a2b7171725964614e41336a4362695a32425276596447384e42434d644d73356241416e76797a6c45513d/o00407-4003700010101.logjez')
r.status_code

r.text # the file appears to come but I think it's not the right way to do it, when I automate it to look for another section (if) I won't have the correct file name
```

[image]

How can I automate something like this without knowing what the name of the next file will be when I change the ulr?
Thanks!

Comment: `r.content` or `r.text`  is holding all the data. if you dont need the data for extra processing in python, you might be able to get away with just saving the zip: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126596/saving-response-from-requests-to-file

Comment: I understood this but I was only able to do it because I took the ulr in the inspect element, I want through the mother url to know the ult and the name of the file to do the get and thus automate my script

Comment: Have a random session token too

Comment: @LeonardoHenriques what you click from main page?

Comment: I would suggest using something like selenium - according to the dev tools, the event handler for when than download button is clicked is in the `polyfills-es2015.....js`  file and it does *not* look easy to parse and/or reverse-engineer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by

> change "zn" and "se" in the url

but you might want to try this:

```py
import os
import time
import urllib.parse
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copyfileobj

import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0",
    "Referer": "https://resultados.tse.jus.br/oficial/app/index.html",
}


def download_file(source_url: str, directory: str) -> None:
    os.makedirs(directory, exist_ok=True)
    save_dir = Path(directory)
    file_name = (
        f"LogDeUrna_Totalizado_{int(time.time())}"
        f"_{source_url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1].replace('.logjez', '')}"
        f".vscmr.zip"
    )
    destination = save_dir / file_name
    with s.get(source_url, stream=True) as file, open(destination, "wb") as output:
        copyfileobj(file.raw, output)


with requests.session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    base_url = 'https://resultados.tse.jus.br/oficial/app/index.html#/m/dados-da-urna;e=e545;uf=mg;ufbu=mg;mubu=40037;zn=0001;se=0101/log-de-urna'
    # deconstruct the url to get the query parameters
    url_parts = (
        urllib.parse
        .urlsplit(base_url.rstrip("/log-de-urna").rsplit('/', 1)[-1])
        .path.split(';')[2:]
    )
    # build a map of the query parameters
    d = dict([part.split('=') for part in url_parts])

    # rebuild the API url with the query parameters
    api_url = f"https://resultados.tse.jus.br/oficial/ele2022/arquivo-urna/407/dados/mg/" \
              f"{d['mubu']}/{d['zn']}/{d['se']}/" \
              f"p000407-mg-m{d['mubu']}-z{d['zn']}-s{d['se']}-aux.json"
    # get the API response and extract the hashes
    hashes = s.get(api_url).json()['hashes'][0]
    # build the download url with the hashes and query parameters
    zip_url = f"https://resultados.tse.jus.br/oficial/ele2022/arquivo-urna/407/dados/mg/" \
              f"{d['mubu']}/{d['zn']}/{d['se']}/" \
              f"{hashes['hash']}/{hashes['nmarq'][3]}"
    # download the file
    download_file(zip_url, 'zip_files')
```

This should download a file like this:

```
LogDeUrna_Totalizado_1667737288_o00407-4003700010101.vscmr.zip
```

Which should have this (after extraction it's just a `.dat` file):

*shortened for brevity*

```
24/09/2022 16:16:19 INFO    67305985    LOGD    InÌcio das operaÁıes do logd    25DB7401100B3F08
24/09/2022 16:16:19 INFO    67305985    LOGD    Urna ligada em 24/09/2022 ‡s 16:15:04   43FBAE51FE13D6F8
24/09/2022 16:16:19 INFO    67305985    SCUE    Iniciando aplicaÁ„o - Oficial - 1∫ turno    46556A8AF2E2C406
24/09/2022 16:16:19 INFO    67305985    SCUE    Vers„o da aplicaÁ„o: 8.26.0.0 - OnÁa-pintada    7827EE0DB8CA11F0
24/09/2022 16:16:21 INFO    67305985    SCUE    Urna operando com rede elÈtrica 239A67E5FCA5752B
24/09/2022 16:16:21 INFO    67305985    SCUE    Bateria interna com carga plena 6EE1D58F43F1C55E
24/09/2022 16:16:27 INFO    67305985    SCUE    Tamanho da mÌdia interna: 488.7 MB  3C1DD481446A0EB8
24/09/2022 16:16:30 INFO    67305985    SCUE    Tamanho da memÛria: 489.4 MB    D77DD903E0DDB80B
24/09/2022 16:16:30 INFO    67305985    SCUE    VerificaÁ„o de assinatura de aplicaÁ„o por etapa [1] - [/bin/avbin.vst] - [SUCESSO] 07D0A24BF9E343B3
24/09/2022 16:16:31 INFO    67305985    SCUE    VerificaÁ„o de assinatura de aplicaÁ„o por etapa [2] - [/uenux/bin/avusrbin.vst] - [SUCESSO]
```

Comment: your script works fine, thank you very much. but after running it I get the error: BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

is there anything that can be changed for the zip to be read?

Comment: How are you unpacking the file, @LeonardoHenriques?

Answer (score 0):

To answer Leonardo's question about reading the zip file: The zip files are compressed with 7zip. To open it use:

```
with py7zr.SevenZipFile(path_to_zipfile, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(temp_dir)
```