# What determines whether a file should be application/octet-stream vs text/plain?

Tags: python, mime

I have a piece of code that handles file uploads for me, and ideally I want to accept only text files (csv, tab delimited files, etc.) So I added this chunk of code:

```
mimetype = magic.from_buffer(request.FILES['docfile'].read(512), mime=True)
if form.is_valid() and mimetype == 'text/plain':
     ....
```

Just recently one of my users tried uploading a text file and the system rejected it, the mime for that file is:

```
file --mime-type -b input_file.txt 
application/octet-stream
```

And of course, all of the previously uploaded files have been text/plain. What's the difference between these two? Is there a more "global" way to check if a file is a text file?

Answer (score 1):

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7392391/1388292) which is probably relevant:

> Yet another method [based on file(1) behavior](https://github.com/file/file/blob/f2a6e7cb7db9b5fd86100403df6b2f830c7f22ba/src/encoding.c#L151-L228):
>
> ```
> textchars = bytearray({7,8,9,10,12,13,27} | set(range(0x20, 0x100)) - {0x7f})
> is_binary_string = lambda bytes: bool(bytes.translate(None, textchars))
> ```
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> is_binary_string(open('/usr/bin/python', 'rb').read(1024))
> True
> is_binary_string(open('/usr/bin/dh_python3', 'rb').read(1024))
> False
> ```

Comment: Would the proper way to handle this to accept both binary and text files then? I ask this because I can technically add application/octet-stream as another mime type

Comment: If you go down that route, yes you need to accept both and test them after. I don't know much about MIMEtypes appart from gtk but it doesn't seem to be 100% reliable.