# How to open only text files in a directory using Python

Tags: python

I was working on a small script in Python where I had to traverse through the directories which have multiple types of files, but I want to open only text files. So how can I do that? Below is my code.

```
import os,re

pat=re.compile(input("Enter the text you want to search for :  "))
fpath=r'C:\Users\Python\Python_my_Scripts\'
for i in os.walk(fpath):
    for fname in i[-1]:
        fpath=os.path.join(i[0],fname)
        try:
            IN=open(fpath,"r")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        else:
            line_num=0
            for line in IN:
                line_num+=1
                if not re.search(r'^\s+#',line):
                    if re.search(pat, line):
                        print("{1:>2d} : {0}".format(fpath,line_num))
```

The code basically breaks in the try segment if a directory contains any non-text file.

Comment: can you add a check to see if the file name ends with `.txt`?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint: No unfortunately i can't do that and infact i don't want to do that, a text file might not have .txt extension.

Answer (score 1):

Use [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to get a list of filenames by pattern:

```
import glob
glob.glob('*.txt')
```

Comment: That's not intended, a file can be a text file and might not have .txt extension.

Answer (score 1):

Using [python-magic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic) you can check the file type, in the same way you would using the [file command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)). You can then check the output from `magic.from_file` to see whether or not the file is a text file.

```
>>> import magic
>>> magic.from_file("/bin/bash")
'ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=75a0ba19d5276d9eb81d6f8e9e2cb285da333296, stripped'
>>> magic.from_file("/etc/fstab")
'ASCII text'
>>> if 'text' in magic.from_file("/etc/fstab").lower():
...     print("a text file...")
... 
a text file...
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over files with `os.walk` or get files with `glob` packages and check whether you file is binary or text for that this might be helpful to you, [How can I detect if a file is binary (non-text) in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898669/how-can-i-detect-if-a-file-is-binary-non-text-in-python).