# Python 3, can I tell if a file opened in binary mode contains text?

Tags: python-3.x, file

I am upgrading some code from python 2 to python 3.

There is a function to open and read files. In Python 2 there is no need to specify binary mode or as a string. While in Python 3 I should specify the mode.

The python 2 code is:

```
with open(f_path, mode=open_mode) as fp:
    content = fp.read()
```

This is causing me problems as it is called by various other functions where I don't necessarily know the file type in advance. (Sometimes the data is written to a zip file, other times the data is returned via an HTTP endpoint).

I expect most data will be binary image files, though CSv and text files will also be present.

What would be the best way of opening a file of unknown type and detecting if it is binary or string data?

Is it possible for example to open a file in binary mode, then detect that it contains text and convert it (or alternatively generate an exception and open it in string mode instead)?

Comment: Are you worried about any alternate encodings other than ASCII/UTF-8? If so, use chardet. If not, then just use binaryornot as suggested below.

Comment: I expect most text files to be encoded in UTF-8, though the user can upload whatever they need. I am going to try the binaryornot and see if that works.

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/898669

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try the binaryornot library.

```
pip install binaryornot
```

Then in the code:

```
from binaryornot.check import is_binary
is_binary(f_path)
```

Here is their documentation:

https://pypi.org/project/binaryornot/

Comment: Chardet is probably a good way to complement it. The weakness of chardet is that is does not detect binary directly (it tries to detect text encoding and usually returns some random text encoding with a small probability when it's binary), but you could use both if performance is not an issue.

Comment: Yeah, I deleted my comment and posed it as a comment to the OP instead. Great answer, by the way.

Comment: So far binaryornot does what I want. I will test a few more cases and see if I actually need chardet as well.